# How to create a master branch when only develop exists in git?

Tags: git, github

I improvised from the following two links to split a subfolder out into a new repository:

- https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/
- http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/

To yield:

```
cd ~/dev/newRepoName && \
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter \
path/to/subfolder -- --all
```

But because my subfolder had never existed anywhere but in `develop` branch, I ended up with a repo that has only the `develop` branch in it.

How do I safely create a `master` branch? ... so that I may then go on using gitflow and all the other good stuff that builds upon a sane git infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just create a new branch 'master' from your current branch develop '`git checkout -b master`'.